# umask 027 and the sudo user

Tags: permissions, sudo, umask

This is sort of a follow on question to [What permissions would change if I change umask to 027 from 022?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420320/what-permissions-would-change-if-i-change-umask-to-027-from-022)

Our IT has changed `umask` from the default 022 to 077 and then to 027 after enough complaints were received. The main issue I have with either 027 or 077 (it was changed in `/etc/login.defs`) is that the `sudo` user also grabs that umask which ends up breaking things in subtle and often infuriating ways. The main issues revolves around installing software / dev tools / libraries that require root privileges.

Normally the libraries will get installed in `/usr/local` which obviously requires the use of `sudo`. The main problem is when the sudo user has one of the higher umasks the files that get installed into `/usr/local` (and hence are owned by `root` and belongs to `root`'s group) are unusable by me once the installation is complete. Yes I could go change the permission of all the files that get installed so they're readable by normal users, but that seems like a horrible solution (when I install software such as `cmake`, how am I suppose to track down all the files it installs?).

I guess I'm trying to figure out how those who advocate using a umask of 027 or 077 make it so `sudo` doesn't inherit that umask or how this problem is normally solved. I can't imagine it's an issue unique to us.

Possible answer here: [Issue with umask UBUNTU 14.04.3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/685813/issue-with-umask-ubuntu-14-04-3)

Comment: The sudoers file has its own umask option - but to allow it to set a more permissive value than that inherited via PAM you need to set the umask_override property as well I think. See for example [Set sudo umask apart from the user calling it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265497/set-sudo-umask-apart-from-the-user-calling-it)